# Typeahead with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement twitter typeahead with rails.
I have done this using searchkick gem and elasticsearch.

There is a slight issue in here,my remote call of BloodHound is like this

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.username);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: "../users/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"
        }
    });
```

Now in here instead of the %QUERY getting substituted with the value of typeahead search box,it just gives the string %QUERY as it is.

Rest everything is working fine because if I goto the url

```
http://localhost:3000/users/autocomplete?query=vive
```

I get the desired results.

Its just that the %QUERY is not getting substituted.

Here is the form

```
<%= form_tag users_path, class:'ui form',method: :get do %>
   <div class="ui small icon input">
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query],class:'typeahead',id:'user_search',placeholder:'Search Breeder' %>
    <i class="search icon"></i>
   </div>
<%end%>
```

And the controller

```
def autocomplete
 render json: User.search(params[:query],autocomplete:true).map{|user| {username:user.username,value:user.id}}           
end
```

/*routes.rb*/

```
resources :users do
   collection do
      get :autocomplete
    end
  end
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Can you show the search method in your user model?

Answer (score 0):

Alright after struggling a lot to find an answer to this,I somehow got it working.

So for anyone who is stuck at the same place,here is the solution:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.username);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: "../users/autocomplete?query=%QUERY",
            //add wildcard to make it work
            wildcard:"%QUERY"
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps someone.